# Using apache bench on local server

Tags: php, apache, webserver, web-testing, apachebench

I want testing my site load  (site is write on php) via apache bench.

I have local server (xampp), OC: windows.

In directory apache/bench there is file ab.exe, this means that apachebench is installed in my local server yes?

I have local site localhost/my_test, I want simulate concurrent 1000 request on this site, in CMD I write this command:

**ab -c 1000 localhost/my_test**

answer from CMD is:  **'ab' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**

Tell please, where I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

AB needs a complete URL:
Usage: ab [options] [http://]hostname[:port]/path

So, in your case the URL should look like:
localhost/my_test/

It needs the path - which in this case is simply the /

Hope this helps

Paul.

Answer (score 1):

> **ab -c 1000 localhost/my_test**
>
> answer from CMD is: **'ab' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.**

It means that ab.exe not in your PATH.
If you start CMD, first you should navigate yourself into the apache/bench directory, and run the command from that folder.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should type your port that your server has been running on;

For example, I use `http://127.0.0.1:8080` (port is 8080 as I set in my XAMPP config)